# Javascript RegEx , Find Text in Between Square Brackets

Tags: javascript, regex

Find:

```
ellora[sidebar-1]
```

and replace only the number, specially finding text in between square brackets (both opening and closing) and replace.
Using `replace()`

```
method.result
```

should be like this

```
ellora[sidebar-2], ellora[sidebar-3], ...
```

Comment: dynamically increase or decrease by one

Comment: simply i have to replace numeric value only.

Comment: If the edit doesn't make sense, feel free to change it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this:

```
s = s.replace(/(\w+\[\w+[_-])(\d+)(\])/g, function(str, p1, p2, p3) {
    return p1 + (parseInt(p2) + 1) + p3;
});
```

Comment: i don't want to hardcode texts,for sidebar-1,sidebar-2, i was doing replace(/^(.+[_-])([0-9]+)$/,"$1"),Please tell me the pattern for ellora[sidebar-1]

Comment: @Sam3: Erm... how about `/(\w+\[\w+[_-])(\d+)(\])/g`? But I can't really guess the exact regular expression. You need to give more examples, or else describe precisely the allowable range of values that it should match (e.g. "one or more alphanumeric characters, followed by a [, followed by etc...").